# FullStack web project hosting

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, hosting, web-hosting

I want to host a full stack spring boot and react.js project, and I want to know the type of hosting adequate for this project knowing that it is a small project.
shared hosting vs vps hosting

Comment: This is an opinionated question and it is not welcomed on stack overflow. [Refer the questions to not ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Consider [Taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can even earn a badge. And please refer [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Anyways, I'll leave my opinion if it helps on your research. I haven't worked with spring boot. But since you are trying to deploy a small react project check out [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

Comment: A quick google search would take you [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=platforms+to+deploy+java+and+reactjs&oq=platforms+to+deploy+java+and+reactjs+&aqs=chrome..69i57.8208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)... some of the examples would be Heroku, AWS, Netlify etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to deploy your application in spring boot and reacts js most quickly and also no need of additional configuration. Monitoring logs is also easy.

Comment: and can i have my own domaine i heroku?

Comment: yes you can integrate your own domain with heroku also by default heroku provides domain with herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Vercel for small projects. Netlify and Heroku are also good options

Comment: is it a shared hosting or vps hosting?